# How to echo customer Lifetime Sales on admin Order View page

Tags: admin

I'm looking to display the customer Lifetime Sales value (£) within the admin on admin Order View page. I've managed to pull in the customer total order count with the code below, and basically would like to do the same with the lifetime value

```
getOrder()->getCustomerId(); $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer_id); $_orderCnt = $_orders->count(); //orders count ?>
(Including this order): '.$_orderCnt.''; ?>
```

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to simply iterate over the order collection and create a sum of order totals. It could look something like this:

```
$_lifetimeValue = 0;
foreach ($_orders as $_order) {
    $_lifetimeValue += $_order->getGrandTotal();
}
```

You may want to exclude tax and/or shipping amounts, which you can do by using other columns from the `sales_flat_order` table.

Comment: @AlastairHeath - Glad to hear! Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted.